# Replace image in a template created on After Effects

Tags: after-effects, premiere

I've created an intro template on After Effects that has some text and the animation of a masked image. If I import this aep template to Premiere Pro, I can easily replace the text, however I can't find a way to replace the image too.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is.  As you say, you can replace text using [Live Text Templates](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/how-to/animated-text-titles-live-text.html).
If you need to easily re-version comps from AE with different source material, I would suggest looking at [Templater](http://aescripts.com/templater/).

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're running Bridge, you could keep AE open, and then replace the image.

If you've designed a template. I would recommend in AE using a pre-comp called a drop zone. A custom sized comp with guidelines / safe areas that is nested into the final comp. Then you basically can quickly drop any image into the dropzone composition, align/scale, and it will nest into the render comp.

If you dont want to run AE, having bridge running if you simply set a standard for the picture size, as in same size always, crop for import into AE, and then simply replace the photo file on the disk with the new one, using the same name, it will update on the PPro timeline.

As far as doing a replace command inside PPro, from a linked AE project, is not possible.